# Load sparse matrix with Armadillo C++

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, armadillo

I trying to load this [matrix](https://sparse.tamu.edu/Rothberg/cfd1) using `Armadillo` in `C++`.
This is my simple code:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

int main(void) {

  arma::sp_mat matrix;
  matrix.load("./matrix/cfd1.mat", arma::raw_ascii);
  
  return 0;
}
```

At compile time the code doesn't generate any warning but when I run the executable file this is the output:

> warning: SpMat::load(): unsupported file type
>
> warning: SpMat::load(): couldn't read ./matrix/cfd1.mat

I tried to change the `arma::raw_ascii` with `arma::hdf5_binary` but it doesn't work the same.

## EDIT

I think that is not a duplicate because the problem is not the header of the file. Even if I use `arma::auto_detect` the problem persist.
If I use the type `mat` the problem there isn't.

Comment: TL;DR: `raw_ascii` only works if the MATLAB matrix was saved with `-ascii`. `hdf5_binary` only works if the matrix was exported as HDF5 from MATLAB. Neither is the case for the downloadable `.mat` here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Where I can find the correct header for the file?

Comment: @MaxLanghof I just edited the question, this is not duplicated. The questions that you think solve the problem in my opinion have nothing in common

Answer (score 0):

Download the matrix in the so-called "matrix market" format: https://sparse.tamu.edu/MM/Rothberg/cfd1.tar.gz

Extract the matrix from the .tar.gz archive, obtaining `cfd1/cfd1.mtx`. The file has a header that has to be stripped away before the file can be loaded.  Using a text editor, remove the first 14 lines in the mtx file.  The first line should then have `1 1 1`. Save the edited file under the same name.

Load the edited matrix file in Armadillo using the [`coord_ascii`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#save_load_mat) option. You will need a recent version of Armadillo that supports `coord_ascii` (version 9.400 seems to work).

```
sp_mat X;
X.load("cfd1/cfd1.mtx", coord_ascii);
```

In Armadillo matrix indices start at 0 (due to C++ conventions), while in the matrix market file they start at 1. So you need to remove the first row and column from `X` to take this into account. This can be done via [submatrices](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#submat):

```
X = X.tail_rows(X.n_rows-1);
X = X.tail_cols(X.n_cols-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [fast_matrix_market](https://github.com/alugowski/fast_matrix_market)'s Armadillo binding to load the MatrixMarket formatted version of that matrix:

```cpp
#include <fstream>
#include <armadillo>

#include <fast_matrix_market/app/Armadillo.hpp>

int main(void) {
  arma::sp_mat matrix;
  
  std::ifstream f("./matrix/cfd1.mtx");
  fast_matrix_market::read_matrix_market_arma(f, matrix);

  return 0;
}
```

This is like @hbrerkere's answer, but without having to fiddle with the file.